# How can I get my C# program to listen for a keypress held down, when it's not focused?

Tags: c#

I have a small program that I've written in a console application and I'm wondering if it's possible to have it listen to key events when the program is not focused.

For example if I can run the application and while in a different application if I press and hold the alt key my c# program would register the key event and set a boolean to true when the key is held down.

I did find this https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.registerhotkey but I can't figure out a way for it to detect if a key is held down.

Comment: Look into _global keyboard hook_

Comment: @Rufus not really a duplicate as none of those answer detail how it would simulate a keypress while held down.

Comment: You didn't ask about stimulating a key press, you asked about detecting one, right?

Comment: I actually said detecting a kepress held down. I didnt mean simulate, but detect. Stackoverflow wont let me update the comment.